# MySQL Error When Creating Function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting this error when I want to execute below query for creating function, I checked everything it seems that I can't find the issue:

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF price > 1000 THEN
>       BEGIN
>         SET last3 = SUBSTRING(price, -3);   ' at line 18

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE FUNCTION GetPrice(number decimal(10,2), profit decimal (10,2)) RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE price int;
    DECLARE last3 int;
    DECLARE rootn int;
    SET price = CEIL(number + (number * profit /100));
    IF price < 1000 THEN
    BEGIN
      IF (price > 0 and price <= 500) THEN
      SET price = 500;
      ELSEIF (price >500 and price <= 750) THEN
      SET price = 750;
      ELSEIF (price >750 and price < 1000) THEN
      SET price = 1000;
      END IF;
    END
    ELSEIF price > 1000 THEN
    BEGIN
      SET last3 = SUBSTRING(price, -3);
      SET rootn = price-last3;
      IF (last3 >= 0 and price <= 100) THEN
      SET last3 = 0;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 100 and price <= 350) THEN
      SET last3 = 250;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 350 and price <= 600) THEN
      SET last3 = 500;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 600 and last3 <= 850) THEN
      SET last3 = 750;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 850 and price <= 1000) THEN
      SET last3 = 1000;
      END IF;
      SET price = rootn + last3;
    END
    ELSEIF price = 10000 THEN
    SET price = 1000;
    END IF;

 RETURN (price);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Code blocks are delimited with `BEGIN` and `END`, not parentheses. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, I got another error I will update the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to finish `END` with a semicolon:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `GetPrice`(number decimal(10,2), profit decimal (10,2)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE price int;
    DECLARE last3 int;
    DECLARE rootn int;
    SET price = CEIL(number + (number * profit /100));
    IF price < 1000 THEN
    BEGIN
      IF (price > 0 and price <= 500) THEN
      SET price = 500;
      ELSEIF (price >500 and price <= 750) THEN
      SET price = 750;
      ELSEIF (price >750 and price < 1000) THEN
      SET price = 1000;
      END IF;
    END;                              -- here
    ELSEIF price > 1000 THEN
    BEGIN
      SET last3 = SUBSTRING(price, -3);
      SET rootn = price-last3;
      IF (last3 >= 0 and price <= 100) THEN
      SET last3 = 0;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 100 and price <= 350) THEN
      SET last3 = 250;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 350 and price <= 600) THEN
      SET last3 = 500;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 600 and last3 <= 850) THEN
      SET last3 = 750;
      ELSEIF (last3 > 850 and price <= 1000) THEN
      SET last3 = 1000;
      END IF;
      SET price = rootn + last3;
    END;                                   -- and here
    ELSEIF price = 10000 THEN
    SET price = 1000;
    END IF;

 RETURN (price);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bacdc/2)

Comment: I did that but still get an error please run the query if you have mysql installed

Comment: @Akam Interesting. It runs on my machine. Although sqlfiddle refuses it. But I don't know their syntax for delimiters. Please try my codeblock again, I'm running MariaDB 10.

Comment: @robsn sqlfiddle has a drop-down list where you have to select a delimiter; the sanest value available in the drop-down is `//` and the `DELIMITER` directive isn't recognized there, at all. (fwiw)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the hint!